# What is the point of Junos outbound SSH service?

Tags: juniper-junos, ssh

Junos [outbound SSH service](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/software/topics/task/configuration/ssh-outbound-service-configuring.pdf) makes a SSH connection from network device to SSH server. What is the point of this? Does it allow the server to somehow make the SSH connection back to network device using this already established SSH connection?

Comment: You could create a secure tunnel between routers. There are many uses for SSH tunnels, and to a server is only one.

Comment: @RonMaupin It is still a SSH server either it runs on a router, switch or firewall unit. Still, what is the use case for Junos `outbound SSH service` feature? I guess it has something to do with some Juniper zero touch provisioning system.

Comment: As I explained, an SSH tunnel between routers (which are TCP, SSH and tunnel peers) is often very useful. For example, securely connecting two sites remote from each other so that users at each site have secure, private access to the network at the other site.

Comment: Do you mean like site to site VPN over SSH tunnel? If yes, then I'm not sure that this `outbound-ssh` feature does that.. Juniper documentation says that: `Once the connection is established, the management application initiates the SSH sequence as the client and the router or switch as the server that authenticates the client.`. However, I'm not sure how to understand this..

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

In Junos, `outbound-ssh` is used to allow the device to connect back to an external management platform via NETCONF over SSH, allowing remote management of devices that were behind NATs or jump-hosts.

If you use Juniper’s Sky Enterprise management solution (aka OneConfig), they use this method exclusively for device connectivity, configuration changes and even remote console.